# Python: Lookup keys which correspond to an item in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, python-itertools, defaultdict

### Problem Statement

Given a dictionary of lists,

```
key_to_list = {
    'one': [1, 3, 5, 7],
    'two': [2, 4, 6, 8],
    'three': [1, 2, 5, 6],
    'four': [2, 5, 7, 8]
}
```

what is the best way to create a mapping from elements of the lists to their keys?

```
list_element_to_keys = {
    1: {'one', 'three'},
    2: {'two', 'three', 'four'},
    3: {'one'},
    4: {'two'},
    5: {'one', 'three', 'four'},
    6: {'two', 'three'},
    7: {'one', 'four'},
    8: {'two', 'four'}
}
```

### My Solution

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_element_to_keys = defaultdict(set)
for key, value in key_to_list.items():
    for item in value:
        list_element_to_keys[item].add(key)
```

### Thoughts

A friend of mine has suggested it may be possible to use a
dictionary comprehension, but I keep running into issues
because multiple keys have lists that contain some of the same items.

I also think their might be some `itertools` magic that could help,
but I am not positive.

### Dict Comprehension

I have found, with the help of a friend a dictionary comprehension that works.

```
from itertools import chain
list_element_to_keys= { i: set(k for k,v in key_to_list.items() if i in v) for i in set(chain.from_iterable(key_to_list.values())) }
```

Comment: This belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. In any case I think your solution is fine and doesn't need to be changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fine, it works and `defaultdict` is an obvious (good) choice for such a problem.

One thing you could improve is to use `six.iteritems(key_to_list)` that will make it a bit faster on Python2.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do this

```
d = {}; [d.setdefault(i,[]).append(k) for k,v in key_to_list.items() for i in v]
print d
```

this results in

```
{1: ['three', 'one'],
 2: ['four', 'three', 'two'],
 3: ['one'],
 4: ['two'],
 5: ['four', 'three', 'one'],
 6: ['three', 'two'],
 7: ['four', 'one'],
 8: ['four', 'two']}
```

Comment: To match the requested solution it should be `d.setdefault(i,set()).add(k)`. But doing a comprehension just for the side-effects ... I don't know.

Comment: Thanks you @MSeifert, i thought the OP wanted just the mapping. but eitherways, your comment is appreciated.

Comment: I had come up with this at one point, but like MSeifert pointed out, it seems a bit inelegant to use the comprehension just for the side-effects. It is definitely a good way to do it if we were only concerned about code-golfing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it in a one-statement nested comprehension:

- compile a set of the values (new keys)
- for each element of that set, iterate through the original keys
- Where the original key has the new key in its value list,
    include that string in the new key's value list

Code:

```
list_element_to_keys = \
    {new_key : [old_key for old_key in key_to_list.keys() if new_key in key_to_list[old_key]] \
     for new_key in set([item for value_list in key_to_list.values() for item in value_list ])}

print (list_element_to_keys)
```

Output (line feeds added to aid reading):

```
{1: ['one', 'three'], 2: ['two', 'four', 'three'],
 3: ['one'], 4: ['two'],
 5: ['four', 'one', 'three'], 6: ['two', 'three'],
 7: ['four', 'one'], 8: ['two', 'four']}
```

Comment: This is very nice, but it seems like it loses some clarity.

Comment: Yes, it loses clarity.  OP asked for a dictionary comprehension ... :-)